# What user input can cause kCGEventTapDisabledByUserInput

Tags: macos, accessibility, core-graphics, hid, cgeventtap

[CG Event taps](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/coregraphics/1454426-cgeventtapcreate) can be disabled by user input, in which case they receive an event of type [kCGEventTapDisabledByUserInput](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/coregraphics/cgeventtype/kcgeventtapdisabledbyuserinput?language=objc).   But what user input would that be?   What's the magic key chord to disable event taps?

Answer (score 0):

`kCGEventTapDisabledByUserInput` event is received when `CGEventTapEnable` is called with `false`.

However, I'm not sure if there're other options to receive `kCGEventTapDisabledByUserInput`.